# Vue.js Display input div based on input value (number)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I'm working on a  form for a Vue js project and I'm trying to find how I can display input elements based on the inserted input value.
The idea is a booking app. Based on the number of people you have inserted in the input field, inputs have to pop up below.

Below is the data I want to push into an array

```
    data() {
    return {
        info: {
            "date": "2022-11-11T18:00",
            "tracks": 1,
            "people": 4,
            "sneakers": [38, 35, 44, 43]

        },
```

Comment: If you can be more explicit in your example, or what you need.
maybe a mockup or reference can be useful

Comment: You mean like this? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-a-range

Answer (score 0):

When inserting the number 3 inside of the input named " people " I would like to display the number of inputs based on the input value

See Mockup:

[image]